# How I do a reweight a portfolio, given a particular correlation matrix?

Tags: correlation

I have a portfolio of 14 distinct instruments.

Some of the instruments returns are correlated, which means the portfolio is not as diversified as it seems.

Is there a general way to down-weight instruments which are highly correlated, and vice-versa, to make a portfolio as diversified as it can be?

Comment: What's an instrument? Do you have a set of 14 financial assets and wish to find the minimum variance portfolio?

Comment: "Some of the instruments returns are correlated, which means the portfolio is not as diversified as it seems." - no, the conclusion is wrong. Instrument returns are always correlated to some degree, regardless of diversification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A classic question in portfolio theory is what's the minimum variance portfolio of risky assets?

Let $\Sigma$ be the covariance matrix for the returns of your set of assets. Let $\mathbf{w}$ be a vector denoting the portfolio weights. The minimum variance portfolio is the solution $\mathbf{w}^*$ to the optimization problem:

$$
\begin{equation}
 \begin{array}{*2{>{\displaystyle}r}}
 \mbox{minimize (over $w_i$)} & \mathbf{w}'\Sigma \mathbf{w} \\
 \mbox{subject to} & \sum_i w_i = 1
 \end{array}
\end{equation}
$$

Or if you have a no short selling constraint:
$$
\begin{equation}
 \begin{array}{*2{>{\displaystyle}r}}
 \mbox{minimize (over $w_i$)} & \mathbf{w}'\Sigma \mathbf{w} \\
 \mbox{subject to} & \sum_i w_i = 1\\
    & w_i \geq 0
 \end{array}
\end{equation}
$$
The main problem in this exercise is that a poorly estimated covariance matrix $\Sigma$ of risky assets or a $\Sigma$ that changes over time (which it almost certainly the case) may yield garbage estimates of $\mathbf{w}^*$  going forward. Estimates of $\Sigma$ aren't very precise, and if you treat $\Sigma$ as if it were estimated without any error, you may get garbage results.

Also be aware that the returns of financial assets tend to have huge cross-sectional correlation. Diversification averages out idiosyncratic risk but it *cannot* eliminate systemic risk. As you increase the number of assets, the variance of the minimum variance portfolio does not go to zero because of economy-wide, systemic risk: $ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \min \mathbf{w'}\Sigma\mathbf{w} \neq 0$.

Comment: So to be clear, there's no way closed-form way to go from a correlation matrix/covariance matrix to a weights vector? I need to run an optimizer every time?

Comment: @cjm2671 Like many least squares problems, the first optimization problem I listed does have an analytic solution. Solve $\Sigma \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{1}$ and then normalize the weights to 1. Something like `w_mvp = linsolve(Sigma, ones(n, 1)); w_mvp = w_mvp / sum(w_mvp);` Be aware, this may tell you to do bizarre things like go short China 150% and go long Europe 250%. Garbage $\Sigma$ in, garbage weights out.

Comment: Solving a 14 by 14 linear system is entirely trivial: we're talking single digit or double digit *microseconds*. Also there's a tremendous stuff out there if you search for minimum variance portfolio, or minimum volatility, or low volatility.

Comment: OP did not specify the "minimum variance" problem. He wants "as diversified as it can be". For instance, the simplest portfolio - all cash - would have no variance at all. Will it suffice?

Comment: @Aksakal A general principle I follow is that questions should be interpreted reasonably, not literally. I took it the OP had some vague, imprecisely phrased notion of changing security weights based upon the covariance matrix of security returns to "diversify" (which is normally done to reduce volatility). I don't know what the OP precisely wants, but I reasoned that introducing the absolutely classic portfolio optimization problem of finding the minimum variance portfolio among a set of risky assets might be what he's asking for. Or it would get him thinking about his problem more precisely.

Comment: My point is that minimum variance _could_ be a consequence of the diversification. However, it's not in itself a measure of diversification. OP needs to work on the question. It's too vague in its current form.

Comment: @Aksakal I agree on that. If he were 100% in U.S. treasuries and diversified by adding Chinese tech stocks, that would add volatility and add risk under almost any conceivable definition. Diversification isn't the opposite of risk, volatility doesn't measure diversification, and diversification as an objective in and of itself is rather bizarre. Diversify is an action, volatility is a statistic. Some description of what the "instruments" are and what the underlying objective is would improve the question.